# Can I profile CPU usage at a sub-function level in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a very slow web app that I'm trying to optimize (it's a 3d software-renderer). The chrome dev tools profiler has been very helpful in finding bottleneck functions, but sometimes it's not clear what inside that function is the bottleneck. Is there a way to use the profiler to get a more granular glimpse, without refactoring my code into a bunch of trivially tiny functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for line-level profiling, and there's an introduction to this for Chrome here: https://umaar.com/dev-tips/99-line-level-profiling/

It looks like it may be a Canary only feature for now, but certainly nothing too difficult to get going with!